# Rich Text Editor EE6- Redactor

Tags: richtext, rte, ee6, redactor

Is there a way to enable more plugins for the Redactor option of the Rich Text Field in ExpressionEngine 6? I'd like to be able to add some of the other plugins that Redactor has, such as 'fontfamily': https://imperavi.com/redactor/plugins/fontfamily

With Redactor for Craft CMS there is an opportunity to create a custom Redactor config (https://github.com/craftcms/redactor#configuration) so that we can set up any additional plugins we want. I haven't been able to find a similar way to do this in EE.